# Background Picture on a Responsive Login doesn't fit when the screen size changes

Tags: html, css, background, positioning

I created a Login form using HTML, CSS and the background image has white space below the image.

However, when I change the size of the screen, it has white space below the image.

If you look at this picture, this is how it should look like:

Also here is the script for the background image as well as the site wrapping:

```css
@import "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css";

html, body {min-height: 100%;}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;    
  background-image: url(assets/bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    width: 380px;
    margin:7% auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 17px #333;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 75px;
}

.header h1 {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.main {
    text-align: center;
}

.main input, button {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.main button {
    padding-left: 0;
    background-color: #83acf1;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.main button:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #555;
    background-color: #7799d4;
}
.main input:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #555;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.main span {
    position: relative;
}

.main i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1><b>login</b></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm)">

    <div class="row" *ngIf="authError">
                <div class="col-12 alert alert-danger">{{ authError?.message }}</div>
            </div>

            <span>
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input  ngModel #email="ngModel" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email">
            </span><br>
            <span>
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <input  ngModel #password="ngModel" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
            </span><br>

                <button type="submit">login</button>

         <a  style=" text-align:center; display:block;" href="/register">Click here to register</a>

        </form>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pRL3.png)

Comment: Perhaps try to make your layout responsive by using relative units such as % rather than px. Note also that bacground-attachment: fixed is not fully supported on some systems (see [link]caniuse.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the background-image in the .container div. and set the height to 100vh. Since its a login page and users does not need to scroll down. It should look like this:

```
.container{
  background-image: url(assets/bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

---